# eth_sendTransaction vs eth_sendTransactionAsync - asynchronous or synchronous request

Tags: json-rpc, quorum

Understand that eth_sendTransactionAsync was added in Quorum. eth_sendTransactionAsync returns immediately to allow sending many private transactions/bursts of transactions without waiting for the recipient parties to confirm receipt of the encrypted payloads.

Why eth_sendTransactionAsync isn't available/implemented in the public ethereum JSON RPC as well? Is the use of optional callback as way to do asynchronous call?

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC

Answer (score 3):

The requirements for private txn (Quorum only) posts are a lot different than a regular txn (vanilla Ethereum) mainly because the underlying privacy layer is handled as another p2p communication network and the timing it takes to encrypt and transfer the payload between constellation nodes. Essentially, Ethereums sendTrascation is already async since its posted to a single node, while in private txn mode in Quorum multiple nodes are involved.